# How to add Indian rupee symbol to the RadioButtonList control in asp.net using CSS design

Tags: asp.net, css

I have created a web page which will add an Indian rupee symbol to the HTML element. But now I want to add it to the ASP.NET control `RadioButtonList`. How do I add an Indian rupee symbol to the `RadioButtonList` control in ASP.NET using CSS design?

For example i have done following thing for the html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="rupees.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.webrupee.com/font">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
         <span class="WebRupee"> Rs</span><span >1000</span>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

for this the css design is as follows

```
@font-face{font-family:‘WebRupee’;src:url(‘WebRupee.V2.0.eot’);src:local(‘WebRupee’), url(‘WebRupee.V2.0.ttf’)format(‘truetype’),url(‘WebRupee.V2.0.woff’)format(‘woff’),
url(‘WebRupee.V2.0.svg’)format(‘svg’);font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}
.WebRupee{font-family:’WebRupee’;}
html>body.WebRupee{margin-right:2px;}
html>body.WebRupee{*margin-right:0;}
```

I want to do same for the asp.net control. Is It possible?

Below is the code generated for by browser for RadioButtonList control-

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title><link href="rupees.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.webrupee.com/font" /></head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="RupeesProblem.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTcyMzk2OTU4M2RkdcYvBUoxXiWN7YJOjB8Ix2kUJK0=" />
</div>

<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBQL9g+WlDQKvu9S8DQL7vKHVCAKQkaOMDQKDmNvQBRIdCsAnK66SRJlauJNX6/Qy0f6E" />
</div>

   <table id="rd1" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="rd1_0" type="radio" name="rd1" value="first" /><label for="rd1_0">first</label></td><td><input id="rd1_1" type="radio" name="rd1" value="second" /><label for="rd1_1">second</label></td><td><input id="rd1_2" type="radio" name="rd1" value="third" /><label for="rd1_2">third</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: ah, no: I meant when the server renders `<asp:RadioButtonList>` as HTML and sends it to the browser, what does *that* look like? (View Source in your web browser — you’ll see some HTML where `<asp:RadioButtonList>` was in your ASPX file.)

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: sorry for misunderstanding. I have edited the code part.

Comment: no problem, and thank you for the edit. I’ve updated my answer accordingly. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, the issue:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rd1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
        <asp:ListItem Text="first"><span  class="WebRupee">Rs</span><span >1000</span></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="second"><span class="WebRupee">Rs</span><span >1000</span></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="third"><span class="WebRupee">Rs</span><span >1000</span></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, try adding `CssClass='rupeeRadioButtonList'` to your `<asp:RadioButtonList>` tag. Hopefully this should result in the `<table>` tag in the rendered HTML having a `class="rupeeRadioButtonList"` attribute.

If that doesn’t work, you can wrap the `<asp:RadioButtonList>` tag in a `<div>` with that class:

```
<div class="rupeeRadioButtonList">
    <asp:RadioButtonList>....
</div>
```

Then you’ve got two CSS options:

1. Use the `::after` pseudo-element and the `content` property to add the rupee symbol after the `<label>` tags:

   ```
   .rupeeRadioButtonList label::after {
       content: ' ₹';
   }
   /* (You can use ::before instead if the rupee symbol should go before the <label>) */
   ```

   (Make sure your stylesheets are saved and served with UTF-8 encoding, or any encoding that includes the rupee symbol.)
2. However, `::after` and `content` aren’t supported by Internet Explorer until version 8 (all other browsers support it), so you might instead (or just for older versions of IE, via [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)) want to use a background image:

   ```
   .rupeeRadioButtonList label {
       padding-right: 20px;/* Or whatever’s appropriate for your image */
       background: url(rupeeimage.gif) right center no-repeat;
   }
   ```